# Identifying a type of scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm looking to build a site that acts similar to the link below, and want to find some online tutorials on how to achieve the scrolling affect.

Can anyone tell me what this type of scrolling is called?

http://pelicancreative.com/finaltest3/

Comment: You need to have a problem, this is a Q+A Site.... or is it :/

Comment: It is a jquery plugin. See here: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Answer (score 2):

The different scrolling speeds of the background and foreground content is called parallax